# Getting CaptureInfo from Chromium captured offscreen tab

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, chromium

Using the [off-screen tab capture API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabCapture#method-captureOffscreenTab), how can I get the state of the captured tab?

`chrome.tabCapture.getCapturedTabs()` doesn't provide information for off-screen tabs.  `chrome.tabCapture.captureOffscreenTab()` has no return value... no reference to the tab or tab index.  `chrome.tabCapture.onStatusChanged` doesn't seem to fire for off-screen tabs.

Additionally, is there any way to get the title of the page?

Comment: What "state" are you wanting to get?

Comment: @Makyen Ideally, something in the CaptureInfo enum.  https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabCapture#type-CaptureInfo  `pending`, `active`, `stopped`, or `error`.  But, I'll take anything I can get.  It seems the only thing I can do is work with the media stream tracks... something more related to the page would be helpful.  If I could determine if the DOM loaded or not, that would be even better... but I suspect that one is going to be hard due to the isolation.

Comment: `get the title of the page` see docs for chrome.tabs.query and chrome.tabs.get.

Comment: @xOxxOm Unfortunately these captured off-screen tabs do not show up with the normal `chrome.tabs` methods.